# From one host to another

Tags: riddle, haiku

> All actions you do
> Can make you get me, or not
> If you're bad, I run
>
> The more you get me
> The less you need me for things
> To selfish, I'm all
>
> Up and down, I go
> From one host to another
> Positive? Perhaps...

What am I?

New Verse:

> You have me, pockets!
> Not real, not fake, not in.
> You has some to give

Comment: You like your haikus

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why.

Comment: No. It's suppose to be has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

> Reputation

Now you give me some of it

All actions you do
Can make you get me, or not
If you're bad, I run

> you get reputation for everything you do either bad or good rep

The more you get me
The less you need me for things
To selfish, I'm all

> the more reputation you have, the lesser you will need to do stuff and some selfish people care about reputation only

Up and down, I go
From one host to another
Positive? Perhaps...

> as people vote answers or questions reputation goes from one host to other

You have me, pockets!
Not real, not fake, not in.
You has some to give

> i didn't get this part fully but last line says "You" (the owner of riddle) has some reputation to give

Comment: No. This doesn't comply with the 2nd line.

Comment: You did it! YAY!! (But you have to explain to get accepted.)

Answer (score 3):

> Self confidence/confidence

This was a good one:

> All actions you do can give you self-confidence or not, if you do something wrongly you lose your self-confidence.
> The more self-confidence you have the less you need to be confident to do something, as you know you can do it. Selfish refers to the 'self' confidence
> Your confidence goes up and down, you can give others confidence and sometimes your confidence can make you do something stupid, so its not always positive

Comment: I have an obvious problem with false positives. This fits the riddle, but it isn't the answer intended.

Comment: Nooooo, I thought I had it then

Comment: I'll add another verse.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I got it this time:

> Money

Reasoning:

> Everything you do can help you get money or lose money. The more money you have the less money you need to buy something. Your money goes up and down and goes from one person to another. It is not always a good thing.

The last verse helped:

> You keep your money in your pocket, you have money to give

Comment: No. The 2nd line of the last verse doesn't comply.

Comment: Nope? Wow this one is tough!

Comment: It's like money. But it's not.

Comment: @You is it wealth?

Comment: It's not related to money.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to give the same answer as crybaba... Let's try this:

> Experience

Comment: Interesting, I'm pretty sure its a non-physical thing or an abstract noun

Comment: Extremely close. It's a type of XP.